# Predicting the percentage accuracy based on limited features

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

A practice problem based on whether or not and with what **accuracy/probability** an uber ride gets completed after being ordered has the following features:

```
Available Drivers     int64
Placed Time           float64
Response Distance     float64
Car Type              int32
Day Of Week           int64
Response Delay        float64
Order Completion      int32 [target]
```

My approach has been to use tf.Keras Sequential to predict the target. Here's what it looks like:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

adam_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)

binary_crossentropy_loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()

model.compile(optimizer=adam_optimizer,
              loss=binary_crossentropy_loss,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=ES_PATIENCE)

history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=validation_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=2,
                        callbacks=[early_stop])
```

I normalize the data like this (note that train_data is a dataframe):

```
    train_data = tf.keras.utils.normalize(train_data)
```

And then for predicting,

```
predictions = model.predict_proba(prediction_dataset, batch_size=None)
```

Training results:

```
loss: 0.3506 - accuracy: 0.8817 - val_loss: 0.3493 - val_accuracy: 0.8773
```

But this still gives me a poor quality probability for the corresponding occurrence. Is this the wrong approach ?

What approach would you suggest for a problem like this and am I doing it completely wrong ? Are Neural Networks a bad idea for this solution? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you framed the problem, this is a **classic machine learning classification problem**.

Given N features(independent variables) you have to predict 1(one) dependent variable.

The way in which you constructed the neural network is good.

Since you have a binary classification problem, the sigmoid activation is the correct one.

With respect to the complexity of your model (number of layers, number of neurons per layer) it depends very much on your dataset.

If you have a comprehensive dataset with a lot of features and a lot of examples(an example is a row in dataframe with X1,X2,X3... Y), where X are the features and Y the dependent variable, your model can vary in complexity.

If you have a small dataset with a few features, a small model is recommended. Always begin with a small model.

If you run into the issue of **underfitting** (poor accuracy on the training set and also on the validation and test set), you can **gradually increase the complexity of the model** (add more layers, add more neurons per layer).

If you run into the issue of **overfitting**, implementing regularisation techniques may help (Dropout, L1/L2 Regularisation, Noise Addition, Data Augmentation).

What you have to take into consideration is that, if you have a small dataset, then a classical machine learning algorithm could outperform the deep learning model. This happens because neural networks are very 'hungry' ---> as compared to machine learning models, they require much more data in order to properly work. You could choose SVM/Kernel SVM/Random Forest/ XGBoost and other similar algorithms.

EDIT!

Whether or not and with what accuracy/probability automatically splits the problem into two parts, not only a simple classification one.

What I would personally do is the following: Since the probabilities occur between 0% and 100%, if you had probability as a feature in your X columns (which you don't), then, according to the number of data points(rows) you have you could do the following: **I would assign a label to each probability section**: 1 to (0%,25%), 2 to (25%, 50%), 3 to (50%,75%), 4 to (75%, 100%). But that depends exclusively on the prior probability information(if you had the probability as a feature). **Then if you inferred and you get label 3, you would know the probability of the ride being completed.**

Otherwise, you cannot frame your current problem as both a classification and a probablity one.

I hope that I have given you an introductory insight. Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The dataset has ~15k entries so it is small and using a single layer network may be better, as you said. I've updated my question with some additional info. Could you have a look

Comment: I need to have more information in order to give you a good suggestion. If the answer contributes to understanding better/improve your model, please mark it as accepted. I will have a look once you give me more information.

Comment: Sure thing. Do you require more info on the data ? As for predictions, I sampled randomly from the test dataset and compared the predicted probabilities with the ground truth. I also tried XGBoost and got random-ish probabilities again

Comment: Tell me the accuracy and validation_accuracy. Randomish on your test dataset means that the acc is around 50%?

Comment: That's the issue, they are like ~87% each. That's why I am confused

Comment: 87% is not random. 87% actually is very good for a binary classification problem.

Comment: The results are pretty good. You have neither overfitting nor underfitting. I guess you should focus on how to improve even more the results.

Comment: I am adding new information to the answer, please look it up.

Comment: Yes, I used a dropout layer and early stopping to check over fitting. and yet my prediction probabilities seem pretty random..

Comment: okay, I will check it out. Also, on a sidenote, do you think using tf.estimator would be better and more 'professional' for this ?

Comment: Whatever tools is suitable for you is the professional one :D. If it solves your issue, then you don't need to trouble yourself with other details.

Comment: probability is not a feature. The target goal is binary. the model is supposed to predict with how much accuracy can it know that it will happen. So do you think I should solve this with regression instead ? Or something else ?

Comment: but I need to know the certainty with which my classification is correct. I tried using `model.predict_proba()` but clearly it is not working as it should and is giving me strange probabilities.

Comment: Well, for that you will need to implement the so-called Bayesian Network. A good start reading point is the following. https://medium.com/neuralspace/bayesian-neural-network-series-post-1-need-for-bayesian-networks-e209e66b70b2

Comment: yes, this was the kind of solution I was looking for! (I think) Thanks again!  My solution(given above) was clearly too simplistic for the problem. So many hidden branches of ML applications.. I'll give your answer the tick

Comment: Yes. Please pay attention, even though they may require this approach, several studies show that BNetworks don't do better in final accuracy than others.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing classification, you may want to look into ensemble methods (forests, boosts, etc.)

If you are calculating probability, you may want to look into probabilistic graphical models (Bayesian networks, etc.)

Comment: yep, looking into bayesian models like Timbus mentioned. My solution(given above) was clearly too simplistic for the problem